# Build Failed Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 8s
>   ******************************************************************************************* The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities
>   in this Flutter app. See https:/goo.gl/CP92wY for more information on
>   the problem and how to fix it.
>   ******************************************************************************************* Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**in my pubspec.yaml file**

> dependencies:   flutter:
>       sdk: flutter   flutter_localizations:
>       sdk: flutter
>
> # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
>
> ## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2   image_picker: ^0.4.12+1   image_cropper:
>
> ^1.0.1   http: ^0.12.0+1   sqflite: ^1.1.3   path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
>   rxdart: ^0.21.0   share: ^0.6.0+1   shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2
>   flutter_svg: ^0.12.1   material_search: ^0.2.8   flushbar: ^1.3.0
>   connectivity: ^0.4.3+1   flutter_bloc: ^0.9.1   bloc: ^0.11.2   dio:
>   ^2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

its right in the warning message

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

update your kotlin plugin in the gradle file to 1.3.0

Comment: I did it. but not working. I edited my question please help me

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade my kotlin version to something later - I chose 1.3.60 and my gradle version to 3.5.2 in my android-level build.gradle:

```
// android/build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // Google Services plugin
    }
}
```

I then had also to upgrade my gradle distribution url:

```
// android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

I was able to successfully `flutter run` after changing these.